# Error when installing NFS service on Windows 2016

Tags: nfs, windows-server-2016

When I try to install the NFS service on windows 2016 it fail.
In the system event log I've got 3 errors:

```
- The Server for NFS Open RPC (ONCRPC) Portmapper service failed to start due to the following error: 
A device attached to the system is not functioning.

- The Server for NFS Driver service depends on the Server for NFS Open RPC (ONCRPC) Portmapper service which failed to start because of the following error: 
A device attached to the system is not functioning.

- The Server for NFS service depends on the Server for NFS Driver service which failed to start because of the following error: 
The dependency service or group failed to start.
```

Any idea what can I check to solve this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I discover that Portmapper need to bind the port 111 during the installation process.
In my case the **Veeam vPower NFS Service** was using the port.
after stopping the service **Veeam vPower NFS Service**

1. Check if something is listening on the port
   Open a command prompt and type:

   ***netstat -aon | findstr 111***
2. Stop the process responsible of using the port.

**WARNING**: If your server is in production, stopping a service may have some side effect. If you are unsure, your best bet is to plan an intervention off production time.

3. Install the NFS service.
4. Restart the service stopped in the *step 2*.

Answer (score 4):

Q: Any idea what can I check to solve this?

A: You can force WS2016 to work as NFS server but it won't be any good: Performance isn't great, and Microsoft (OK, University of Chicago actually) Windows NFS server stack is missing from major HCLs (VMware, Citrix etc). It would be a better idea to a) enable Hyper-V role, and b) install FreeBSD or Linux to make one of these guys work as a compatible and high performing NFS server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but this server is our backup server and we need it to be on Windows 2016 with both CIFS and NFS share. By the way, I manage to fix the issue.

Comment: That's a whole different thing: SMB3 & NFS pointing to the same content. Samba is pretty anemic still.